# Gradle equivalent of maven-versions-plugin

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, maven-versions-plugin

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
group 'whatever'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

...

dependencies {
    compile 'whatever:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

I want to automate releasing process, which includes the need to set both versions to particular values, e.g. `1.1.0` or `2.2.0` using command line only. Any kind of autoincrement is not an option.

With Maven, I'd do this using `maven-versions-plugin`:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=${WHATEVER_NEW_VERSION}
```

How can I do the same with Gradle? I only found [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/changing-the-version-in-all-the-submodules-of-a-multimodule-grails-project/2658) unanswered question. There must be some simple way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up extracting version numbers to `gradle.properties` and updating them as part of the automated build script using sed:

```
sed -i -e \"/someVersionNumber=/ s/=.*/=${SOME_NEW_VERSION_NUMBER}/\" gradle.properties
```

It's what I want. Although for me, coming from the Maven background, this doesn't seem natural. I may research another alternative later.

Comment: I like the Maven on Steroids pattern which is close to what you’re describing here.

1. Set the checked-in version to 0-SNAPSHOT
2. Update the version dynamically on release.
See: https://austenconstable.com/2019-11-17-grade-on-steroids and the original Maven concept from Axel Fontaine here: https://axelfontaine.com/blog/final-nail.html

Answer (score 3):

Though not related to publishing, one way to pass command-line properties is as follows:

```
gradle -PWHATEVER_NEW_VERSION=2.0.0
```

Consider the following `build.gradle` snippet:

```
def newVersion = project."WHATEVER_NEW_VERSION"
println newVersion
```

See `~/utils/gradle/version.gradle` in [this project](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_egg_jenkins_artifactory) for another approach. It uses separate environment variables for major, minor, and incremental versions and then builds the string automatically. Because it resides in the `gradle` directory, it can simply be imported into `build.gradle`, which hides some boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used [Axion Release Plugin](https://axion-release-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) a couple of times and was very satisfied. Functionality-wise it comes the closest to what Maven's

Answer (score 0):

I've added this line on `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
version = System.getenv("NEW_VERSION") ?: "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

Not completely equivalent but works fine inside CI/CD scripts.